# Convert CSV with WKT Polygon Geometry to Shapefile - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, geopandas, shapefile

I am trying to convert a CSV file with WKT Polygon geometry to shapefile in Python, but cannot determine how to correctly integrate the geometry into a shapefile.  Below is a segment of the CSV file:

```
    ID  Day Number  Hours      WKT
    1   10  2      [12,12,13]  POLYGON ((153.101112401 -27.797998206, 153.097860177 -27.807122487, 153.097715464 -27.8163131, 153.100598081 -27.821068293,...)
```

I am attempting to use the geopandas and shapely libraries and have found documentd to support conversion from CSV to Shapefile from Points geometry and using latitude/longtitude, but I cannot figure out how to do so without lat/lon and from Polygon geometry.  When I attempted to plot the data, I get an "AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry')".  I can still generate a plot graphic, but there is no data associated with it.  Once I can plot the data, I should be able to generate the desired shapefile output that preserves the attributes of the original CSV.  Below is the the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

test_file = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\sample_data.csv")  ## read the CSV
test_file['geometry'] = test_file.WKT.apply(wkt.loads)  ## load the WKT geometry
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(test_file, geometry='geometry')  ## load CRS into Geodataframe

test_file_gdf.plot(markersize = 1.5, figsize = (10,10))  ## plot the data

## Obtaining the ESRI WKT
ESRI_WKT = 'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]'

## Saving to shapefile
test_file_gdf.to_file(filename = "C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\test_sample.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", crs_wkt = ESRI_WKT)
```

I feel like this should otherwise be fairly straightforward, but I cannot figure out the missing steps in the geodataframe geometry integration, any assistance is most appreciated!

Comment: The AttributeError indicates you did not specify a 'geometry' column in your GeoDataFrame constructor. e.g `gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry='WKT')`

Comment: PeaceLeka - Thank you for clarifying, this did in fact help me get to the correct solution.  I made a couple edits to my initial question, but ultimately got what I needed.  I will acknowledge your answer as the correct solution, thanks again!

Comment: PeaceLeka - One last question, though the updates to the code above work in outputting the shapefile with all attributes/projection information, I tried to re-run the code on a different system and received an error associated with "crs_wkt = ESRI_WKT" stating that "TypeError: open() got multiple values for keyword argument 'crs_wkt'.  Do you know what may be causing this, perhaps an incompatible version of fiona?  I am using geopandas v0.9.0 and fiona 1.8.13 on the other machine, thanks again!

Comment: Set crs on the GeoDataFrame with `gdf.set_crs` and drop the `"crs_wkt = ESRI_WKT"` argument when saving to shapefile.

Comment: PeaceLeka - Thanks for the trip.  I actually just set my crs = {"init:" "epsg"4326"} and declared "crs = crs" to write the shapefile to file and it works great.  Thanks again for your help!